# Joining tables with a substring before a character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, join

I am trying to join tables. The joining column is a contract number. The table I am trying to join it to has multiple contract numbers, each seperated by commas (ie. `Contract1,Contract2,Contract3`).

I have tried using a `LEFT CHARINDEX`, and a `SUBSTRING CHARINDEX`, but none are working.

The join I have tried doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tblA AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblB AS tmp WITH(NOLOCK) 
      ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.Contract_No) = 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEFT(tmp.ContractNo, CHARINDEX('-', tmp.ContractNo) - 1))
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result  - as formatted text, not images. Simplify if needed, [mcve].

Comment: Never store data as comma separated values, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to join which I have figured out is

```
SELECT *
FROM  tblA AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblB AS tmp WITH(NOLOCK) 
      ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.Contract_No) = 
SUBSTRING(tmp.ContractNo,0,CHARINDEX(',',tmp.ContractNo,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical method is to search for a string in a CSV list is to use the following condition:

```
',' + tmp.ListOfContract_No + ',' like '%,' + c.Contract_No + ',%'
```

From your existing query it is unclear which column contains the list of contract numbers and which contains the single contrat, so I renamed the columns to be more talkative. I also do not see the need to convert to `varchar` - as far as concerned both columns should be of that datatype already of they contain values like `'Contract1'`.

Please note that this method is both inefficient and obsfucated. You *really* should be fixing your schema to store each item of the CSV list in a separate table row. Storing CSV lists in columns of a relational database is a bad practice and the root of many evils. More on this [in this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716) (it relates to MySQL but would equally apply to SQL Server).